# How to install the app only once for the suite

Tags: ruby, calabash, calabash-android

I have an app installation hook file like

```
    require 'calabash-android/management/app_installation'

AfterConfiguration do |config|
    FeatureNameMemory.feature_name = nil
end

Before do |scenario|
  @scenario_is_outline = (scenario.class == Cucumber::Ast::OutlineTable::ExampleRow)
  if @scenario_is_outline 
    scenario = scenario.scenario_outline 
  end 

  feature_name = scenario.feature.title
  if FeatureNameMemory.feature_name != feature_name \
      or ENV["RESET_BETWEEN_SCENARIOS"] == "1"
    if ENV["RESET_BETWEEN_SCENARIOS"] == "1"
      log "New scenario - reinstalling apps"
    else
      log "First scenario in feature - reinstalling apps"
    end

    uninstall_apps
    install_app(ENV["TEST_APP_PATH"])
    install_app(ENV["APP_PATH"])
    FeatureNameMemory.feature_name = feature_name
    FeatureNameMemory.invocation = 1
  else
    FeatureNameMemory.invocation += 1
  end
end

FeatureNameMemory = Class.new
class << FeatureNameMemory
  @feature_name = nil
  attr_accessor :feature_name, :invocation
end
```

Here it will reinstall the apps for every feature. but i want the app to be installed only once ,
so how to change this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this thread on the calabash-android google group that sounds like what you are asking for.

It says delete these 3 lines
 uninstall_apps
    install_app(ENV["TEST_APP_PATH"])
    install_app(ENV["APP_PATH"])

Then make sure to install app when you start your tests.

For the full post see this link
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/calabash-android/Ql3iluRMijg
The reply by Preeti Jindal.